# What is the best way to handle LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been struggling with Hibernate lately. I recently ran into a problem which I would appreciate some help with. I have two entities :

1.User

```
@Entity
public class User{

@ID
private Long id;

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Activity> activities;

...
}
```

2.Activity:

```
@Entity
public class Activity {

@ID
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
private User user;

...
}
```

So here, since I didn't set user activities fetchType to EAGER, when I fetch user entity from the database all the activities will be fetched lazily.

What I did in UserRepository was:

```
@Override
public User getUserByUserName(String userName) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery
            ("from User u where u.userName = :user_name", User.class);
    query.setParameter("user_name", userName);
    try{
        return (User) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch(NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Doing this I get The LazyInitializationException when I wanted to use the fetched User's activies. But what I did was removing finaly block from the code :

```
@Override
public User getUserByUserName(String userName) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery
            ("from User u where u.userName = :user_name", User.class);
    query.setParameter("user_name", userName);
    try{
        return (User) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch(NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
 }
```

This solved The exception. I wanted to know if this is the right way to do it or should I just change user activities fetchType to EAGER?

Comment: The Entitymanager should not be close for the lazy data to be fetched later. Moreover you should usually not create an EntityManager for each call to the method.

Comment: You should fetch all the data you need. For example. `from User u join fetch u.activities where u.userName =:userName`. Session should be closed after fetching data. If you keep session open only to fetch associated data, you're keeping connection to DB open, which is not an optimal solution. I cannot tell you how to manage `EntityManager` instance, as I'm always using Spring Boot and everything is managed by Spring. I think you'll find in the documentation about good practices when it comes to managing `EntityManager` instances, `Session`s and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem you're having comes from closing the `entityManager.close();`.

As `User`'s reference to `Activity` is `LAZY`, JPA will load it only once you try to access it via code, like anything accessing the variable `User.activities` in any way.
This makes JPA load the referenced `Activity`s.

**What I *think* happens there:**

1. When you create (read from Database) those `User`s in your `getUserByUserName()` method, JPA keeps (has those created `User`s keep) a reference to the `EntityManager entityManager` they were created with.
2. So if you **later on** try to access `User.activities`, JPA will try to load those activities using the `EntityManager entityManager`.
3. If you have already closed that `EntityManager entityManager` (as you did in your `final` statement), then the loading will fail with that `LazyInitializationException` you then get.

**Solution:**

As I am not sing Hibernate, nor checking its codebase, I do not know whether `entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();` is actually creating separate instances if already present, and how all the `EntityManager` instances are managed.

But probably it's simply best to never close any `EntityManager`; instead, let the JPA implementation (Hibernate) take care of that. With all the possibilities of dependency-injecting stuff into your classes, I bet Hibernate has some pretty good mechanisms in place for dealing with that kind of resource management.

As an alternative, let Hiberante inject the `EntityManager`, so you don't even have to take care of creating it in the first place.

**Finally**, you can still stick to the LAZY loading, if that improves initial and long-term performance for you. Just don't close those `EntityManager`s.

If you need deeper insights into that matter,

- check Hibernate's source code / preprocessors / code injection / bytecode weaving mechanisms
- or use some JVM memory analysis tool to see if the number of instantiated `EntityManager`s increase linearly with calls to your `getUserByUserName()` method.

**Update:** Showing a completely different alternative

I personally use Payara, and use `@EJB private UserCRUD mUserCRUD;` to inject Data Access Objects, that I called CRUD (for Create Retriece Update Delete) a long time ago and still stick to them.

The basic principle is these 3 steps:

**Step 1:** I have a universal base class in a library, injecting the `@PersistenceContext protected EntityManager mEM;`

```
@Stateless
public abstract class TemplateCRUD_Simple<T> implements TemplateCRUD_Simple_Interface<T> {

    @PersistenceContext protected EntityManager mEM;

    protected final Class<T> mType;

    public TemplateCRUD_Simple(final Class<T> pClass) {
        mType = pClass;
    }



    /*
     * INTERNALS
     */

    @Override public String getTableName() {
        return mType.getSimpleName();
    }
    @Override public String getNativeTableName() {
        final Table table = mType.getAnnotation(Table.class);
        if (table != null) return table.name();
        return getTableName();
    }
    @Override public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return mEM;
    }



    /*
     * CREATE
     */

    @Override public T create(final T t) {
        return createAny(t);
    }
    @Override public <U> U createAny(final U u) {
        mEM.persist(u);
        mEM.flush();
        mEM.refresh(u);
        return u;
    }



    /*
     * RETRIEVE
     */

    @Override public T find(final long pID) throws JcXEntityNotFoundException {
        final T ret = find(pID, null);
        if (ret == null) throw new JcXEntityNotFoundException(getTableName() + " with ID " + pID + " cannot be found!");
        return ret;
    }


    @Override public T find(final long pID, final T pDefault) {
        final T ret = mEM.find(mType, Long.valueOf(pID));
        if (ret == null) return pDefault;
        return ret;
    }
    @Override public T find(final Long pID, final T pDefault) {
        if (pID == null) return pDefault;
        return find(pID.longValue(), pDefault);
    }
    @Override public T findCreate(final long pID) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        final T item = find(pID, null);
        if (item != null) return item;

        final T item2 = mType.newInstance();
        return create(item2);
    }

    // a lot more methods here
}
```

And its interface definition, also in the library:

```
public interface TemplateCRUD_Simple_Interface<T> {

    EntityManager getEntityManager();
    String getTableName();
    String getNativeTableName();


    // create
    T create(T t);
    <U> U createAny(U t);

    // retrieve
    T find(long pID) throws JcXEntityNotFoundException;
    T find(long pID, T pDefault);
    T find(Long pID, T pDefault);
    T findCreate(long pID) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException;
    List<T> findAll(String pColName, Object pValue, final boolean pCaseSensitive);
    List<T> findAll(String pColName, Object pValue);
    List<T> findAll(String pColName, String pValue, final boolean pCaseSensitive);
    List<T> findAll(String pColName, String pValue);
    List<T> findAll(String pColName, long pValue);
    List<T> findAllByFieldName(String pFieldName, Object pValue, final boolean pCaseSensitive);
    List<T> findAllByFieldName(String pFieldName, Object pValue);
    List<T> findWhereContains(final String pColName, final String pValue, final boolean pCaseSensitive);
    List<T> findWhereContains(final String pColName, final String pValue);
    List<T> getAll();
    List<Long> getAllIds();
    List<T> getByIds(final Collection<Long> pIds);

    // update
    T update(T t);
    void updateProperties(T pItem, Map<String, String[]> pMatches);
    T updateItem(Map<String, String[]> pMatches, long pID) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException;
    ArrayList<T> updateItems(String pEntityParamName, Map<String, String[]> pMap) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException;

    // delete
    T delete(long pId);

    // misc
    long countAll();
    Object getID(T pItem);
    long getIDLong(T pItem);
    boolean contains(T pItem);
    void detach(final T pItem);

    @Deprecated String getFieldNameInDb(final String pFieldName, final String pDefault);



    //  private List<T> getOverdueForXIn(final int pDays, final String pVarName);
    List<T> getOverdueForDeletion(final boolean pAddAlreadyWarned);
    List<T> getOverdueForUpdate(final boolean pAddAlreadyWarned);

}
```

**Step 2:** For each custom Class I have a CRUD (in this example, the 'User' Class):

- CrudBase_BaseEntity is basically derived drom TemplateCRUD_Simple, just a few more steps in between for more flexibility
- UserCRUD extends TemplateCRUD_Simple, so I can easily use those general methods
- If I need specialized methods, I simply add them to the UserCRUD's code

This is an example for handling the `User` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PT_User")
public class User extends _BaseEntity<User> {...}
```

And this is its CRUD/DAO:

```
@Stateless
public class UserCRUD extends CrudBase_BaseEntity<User> {

    public UserCRUD() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    public long getRegisteredUsersCount() {
        final String sql = "SELECT COUNT(d) FROM " + getTableName() + " d";
        final Query q = mEM.createQuery(sql);
        final Long count = (Long) q.getSingleResult();
        if (count == null) return 0;
        return count.longValue();
    }



    public User findUserByUsernameOrEmail(final String pUid, final String pMail) {
        final TypedQuery<User> query = mEM.createQuery("SELECT i FROM " + getTableName() + " i WHERE lower(i.email)=lower(:userid) OR lower(i.email)=lower(:usermail)", mType);
        query.setParameter("userid", pUid);
        query.setParameter("usermail", pMail);
        final List<User> list = query.getResultList();
        if (list == null || list.size() < 1) return null;
        return list.get(0);
    }



    public List<User> getAllAdmins() {
        final TypedQuery<User> query = mEM.createQuery("SELECT i FROM " + getTableName() + " i WHERE i.isAdmin = TRUE", mType);
        final List<User> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }



    public List<User> getInvalidUsers() {
        final TypedQuery<User> query = mEM.createQuery("SELECT i FROM " + getTableName() + " i "
                + "WHERE (i.username IS NULL"
                + " OR i.fullname IS NULL)"
                + " AND i.email IS NULL", mType);
        final List<User> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }

}
```

**Step 3:** In servlets, I simply inject it via `@EJB`annotation and then use it like this:

```
@WebServlet("/dyn/user/getAll")
@WebServletParams({})
@WebServletDescription()
public class GetAll extends BaseServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4567235617944396165L;

    @EJB private UserCRUD mCRUD;

    @Override protected void doGet_(final HttpServletRequest pReq, final HttpServletResponse pResp) throws IOException {
        USessionManager.ensureUserLoggedInAndAdmin(pReq);

        final List<User> items = mCRUD.getAll();

        items.sort((final User pO1, final User pO2) -> JcUString.compareTo(pO1.getFullname(), pO2.getFullname(), false));

        JSON.send(items, pResp);
    }

}
```

This is the way I implemented it and use it.

- At first it's lot of overhead
- But it's really easy to set up new Classes und CRUDs
- It's safe to use them
- I use this in my JEE library, so I do not have to duplicate code, and any patch or addition I make is then available to all projects that use it
- If need be, I could always access the (again: injected) EntityManager instance inside the TemplateCRUD.

I believe Spring uses a quite similar system, and calls it something like '...Repository'. If you want, you can also check that out and take its source code and adapt it. Usually when doing that, the `@EJB` and `@PersistenceContext` and `@Inject` do not transfer well between GlassFish/Payara, Spring or Hibernate, because not all support all of those Annotations in every context. As I said, this is quite Payara specific, and I've never tested it in other containers, but the approach should work everywhere.

To recap: this all depends a lot on dependency injection, me letting the container do all the work.

Comment: Thanks. That actually helps. 
So, can I basically create only one EntityManager for my entire repository instead of instanciating it for every block of my methods?
Using that single EntityManager in all of my methods and keeping it open throughout the entire applications doesn't it sound a bit odd?!
In that case, what would be the point of EntityManagerFactory anyway?

I just started learning JPA and Hibernate and know nothing about Spring. But I think as you mentioned Spring will take care of all of that.

Comment: I updated the answer with the way I usually handle that. Note that there's a lot of different ways how one could handle all of that. Check out articles on the web for more ideas, what you like best.

Comment: @JayC667 Your code is your rules but I would suggest to look at QueryDSL if you on JEE.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk yeah that looks awesome! Thanx for the hint ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The rule is

> the entities should not escape transaction bounds

The lazy loading is a killer feature of Hibernate, one should not afraid of it.

So, the repository/DAO should return the entity(es).
The service should be transactional(*), manage the entities but return DTOs outside.

Consider using [any java bean mapper](https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks) for that purpose to avoid monkey work.

That allows you not load unnecessary properties if they are not needed.

(*) if there are no long-living operations such as http calls.